# How to get value from a drop-down menu in HTML to use in my Flask app?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm trying to get a value from a drop-down menu that comes from a pandas data frame,
This data frame has some Restaurants information such as(Name, Address, Ratings, etc)
I'm just selecting the Name option here for the customer to be able to select the restaurant Name...
 I need the value that the customer will provide so then I will use this value to predict using my ML code.

So far I got the data frame information selected to shows in a button, however, I don't know how to get this information to use afterwords. 
(Some places they say to use, GET, others to use .
I don't have too much knowledge of javascript.
I'd appreciate your help.

Regards

using Flask.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template,url_for
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

import pandas as pd


app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)


@app.route('/test')
def test():
    data= pd.read_csv("data/restaurants.csv")
    data= data["Name"]
    return render_template('test.html', data= data)
```

test.html

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<style>
.jumbotron {
background-color: #7547bd; 
color: #ffffff;
}
</style>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index">Deep Free from...</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="about">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="test">CUISINE STYLE</a></li>
<li><a href="location">LOCATION</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h1>Choose the restaurant </h1>
<p>See the 5 Similar Cuisine Style</p>
<div class="dropdown">

<center>

<div class="btn-group dropright">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
Select Restaurant
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
<span class="caret">.</span>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu">

</div>



<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
{% for datanum in data %}
<li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
<p></p> <a class="dropdown-item" href=# value={{datanum}} id={{datanum}} >{{datanum}}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</center>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<input type='hidden' id={{datanum}} value=''/>



<center>
<script>

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach( function(el) {

el.addEventListener('click', function() {
var nameres = el.textContent;
document.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle').innerText = nameres;
document.querySelector('#{{datanum}}').value = nameres; 
});
});


</script>
</center> 
<div class="container-fluid bg-">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5">
<p>Contact us and we'll get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Dublin, IRL</p>
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> +383 878119949</p>
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> 10519637@mydbs.ie</p>
</div>

</div>

</div>
</body>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please clean up the formatting of your html/JS, it's very difficult to follow with all the mixed indentation and big gaps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

main.py

```
@main.route("/page", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page():
    if request.method == "POST":
        value_1 = request.form["value_1"]
        # Add code that uses user input here

    context = {
        'dropdown_items' : ["A","B","C","D","E"]
    }
    return render_template('page.html', **context)
```

page.html

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('main.page') }}">
    <label>Dropdop Name: </label>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <select name="start_location">
            {% for x in dropdown_items %}
                <option value = "{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

style.css

```
.custom-select_drop_flight {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select_drop_flight select {
  display: none;
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simpler solution for my case that now shows in a variable...now I'm looking how to send this to my ML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Deep free from...</title>
</head>

<body>



<p id="result"></p>

<select id="resn">
{% for datanum in data %}
<option value={{datanum}} id={{datanum}} >{{datanum}} </option>
{% endfor %}
</select>

<script>

function GetSelectedText(){
var e = document.getElementById("resn");
var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}

</script>

<br/>
<br/>


<button type="button" onclick="GetSelectedText()">Confirm Restaurant </button>
</body>

</html>
```